# Integral of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to find an integral of a matrix
[image]

```
T=[1 1 1]';
R=[1 1];
I=eye(3);
A=diag([1 1 1]');
B=[1 1 1]';
F=[1 1 1];
syms x
G=F*((exp(i*x)*I-A-B*F)\B);
f = T*G*(R*R')*G'*T';
int(f,[0 2.*pi])
```

I am expecting output of 3 by 3 real matrix, but instead I get 3 by 3 matrix with integral and unknown x.

Comment: 1. to begin with, use exp instead of e^
2. is i supposed to be complex? I understand it replaces j in your equasion. If j is a variable it should be included in fun as input
3. make sure you use * for multiplication of matrices and .* for value by value multiplication  
4. since you defined I variable, I suggest you use it instead of eye(3)

Comment: @YuvalHarpaz thanks, I have changed 1., 2. yes, it is complex number, 3. and 4. are also now included

Comment: What makes you think there is something wrong? Share the error message, and the expected result.

Comment: now fun has a 3 by 3 output, for example when running fun(1.5). I'd expect it to yield a single number to make sense

Comment: Your function can't be scalar anyway to be integrated. Have you missed dimensions or multiplications between matrices?

Comment: @Bebs error message: Attempt to execute SCRIPT integral as a function. I expect to receive output that is 3 by 3 real matrix

Comment: @MostafaAyaz, my function isn't scalar, I have $x$ inside the function. Dimensions of the matrices are fine, and overall function is 3 by 3 matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
T=[1 1 1]';
R=[1 1];
I=eye(3);
A=diag([1 1 1]');
B=[1 1 1]';
F=[1 1 1];
G=@(x) F*((exp(1i*x)*I-A-B*F)\B);
f = @(x) T*G(x)*(R*R')*G(x)'*T';
integral(f,0,2*pi,'ArrayValued',true)
```

output

```
7.5398    7.5398    7.5398
7.5398    7.5398    7.5398
7.5398    7.5398    7.5398
```

Comment: I run it, but have this error: "Attempt to execute SCRIPT integral as a function"

Comment: What version is your MATLAB?

Comment: it is MATLAB R2016b

Comment: @Lee this works, I checked. You might have a file somewhere that have a similar name that one of the variables in this script. Please check.